# Does JScript (ES3, in ScriptControl ActiveX object within VBA) support creation of non-enumerable parameters?

Tags: javascript, properties, jscript, enumerable, ecmascript-3

If I define a property/function into an Object prototype (assuming that coercion will eventually lead to every variable accessing the property/function) as such ...

```js
Object.prototype.doFunc = function(){ return 'this is ' + this;}
// OUTPUT - function(){ return 'this is ' + this;}
Object.prototype.doFunc.dontEnum = true
// OUTPUT - True
```

and then I run the `for..in` enumerator on an object, the `doFunc` function also comes up in the enumeration even though the object's `.propertyIsEnumerable('doFunc')` evaluates to a `False`

Any thoughts? (Again this is for ECMA Script 3/JScript that is  native to the ScriptControl object in a VBA project.)

Comment: Does your environment support [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)? If not then most likely not.

Comment: No @Xotic750 it doesn't